# How do I get git add work only on text files?

Tags: git

On a debian server, I want to automate a `git add` command that only adds text files, not binary ones, from a folders tree.

I saw on `git` documentation that `git` doesn't offer this feature, so I found the following solution:

```
/usr/bin/find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 /usr/bin/git add
```

It uses a feature of `grep`, which is capable to distinguish non-text files, and passes the text files names to `git add`.

However, every text file produces a `git add` command, and with many files the command is very slow.

I searched for a way to pass to `git add` a list of files to add, but I couldn't find any.

Is there a way to make `git add` receive the files to add as arguments? Does it make sense?

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: The `xargs` invocation actually batches as many files as possible together to pass to a single invocation of `git add`. I haven't tested, but the expense here is likely the invocation of the `grep` command on every file.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here. Yes, you can specify multiple filenames to `git add` to add them all, such as `git add file1 file2 file3` and then so on. But whether you're able to do so in this case depends on all the other tools, can they build this file list and pass to the final command as such a list?

Comment: why not use some form of `.gitignore`?

Comment: If you don't want binary files to be added, would using `.gitignore` to ignore those files be an option? I assume you're not doing anything crazy, such as putting binary data in a .txt file or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this situation is to use some sort of `.gitignore` pattern to ignore specific types of files, possibly also writing files you'd like to ignore to a specific location.

For example, if you're trying to ignore binary images, you could put `*.jpg`, `*.png`, and `*.gif` (or whatever your formats are). You can also use negative patterns if the ones you'd like to exclude lack extensions, such as typical Unix binary names, although it's easier for you to write all of those binaries in a single `build` directory that is then ignored.

If that isn't possible, for whatever reason, then it's more efficient to use a different invocation. `grep` can specify the names of files it matches, and with the `-I` option, it will match no binary files. So you could make your command more efficient by writing the following:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -IlZ . | xargs -0 git add
```

Note that this command also excludes empty files and possibly files containing only newlines. That may be acceptable for your needs, though.